# What's in the cave?

Tags: riddle

We hide together in our cave

Those who seek us must be brave

---

Most who find us choose to sleep

And those that don't, their widows weep

---

We die but not by hangman's noose

and club or blade won't free us loose

---

Spoiler in edit mode:

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark\bf{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for:

> Intestinal Cancer

```
We hide together in our cave

Those who seek us must be brave
```

> The tumors hide in the 'cave' the intestinal tracks, those that seek them to remove them are doctors/surgeons who need to be smart/brave.

```
Most who find us choose to sleep

And those that don't, their widows weep
```

> If you find out about the cancer, you go under anesthesia (sleep) to have it surgically removed. If you don't find it you can die, which would upset a spouse (who would become a widow).

```
We die but not by hangman's noose

and club or blade won't free us loose
```

> You can remove/kill off the tumors, maybe by surgical removal or by radiation treatment - so not a noose, not a club, and not a blade (at least not a blade alone/directly).

Comment: Actually, this is often killed by a kind of noose. The catch was that it wasn't a hangman's but you are correct . Did you use the spoiler?

Comment: Oh I didn't know that they used a noose, interesting, but it does make sense considering how thin and fragile they are... And I used the spoiler to confirm it after I thought above a body as a cave instead... then thought about that body part to narrow cave down more..

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Bacteria?

We hide together in our cave
Those who seek us must be brave

> Bacteria hang out around the inside of the body. You must be brave to poke around in there o_o

Most who find us choose to sleep
And those that don't, their widows weep

> If you get sick, sleep is good. Not sleeping can be deadly.

We die but not by hangman's noose
and club or blade won't free us loose

> They die all the time. Not sure about the second line.

Comment: Hmm I thought of this too but wasn't entirely sure how to swing each of the lines... I also thought of some pretty fun(gus) solutions for literal caves, but still couldn't get every line to work :)